# SCP from Windows to Linux using Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, scp

I want to do `SCP` from Windows Jenkins node to Linux server. In this set up, Windows machine is a Jenkins slave and the target server where i want to copy is Linux.

Below is my Jenkins pipeline script. Before the below script runs, i am cloning the repository and then building the project which finally creates a `.jar` file. I want to copy this file to Linux server.

```
stage('SCP JAR file') {
    steps {
             bat 'scp /c/Jenkins/workspace/migration/test-project/build/libs/ssupservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar rxp096p@server:/home/rxp096p/testing'
          }
     }
}
```

My working directory is `/c/Jenkins/workspace/migration/test-project/`. Inside the given directory, `build/libs` folder gets created where the required `.jar` file is present.

Running above script gives the following error:

```
/c/Jenkins/workspace/migration/test-project/build/libs/ssupservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error message says the file doesn't exist. What are you looking for here?

Comment: @Kenster I am trying to copy the .jar "ssupservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" to testing directory in linux server.Also i checked the .jar file is present in location.I believe something wrong in syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('SCP JAR file') {
            steps {
                bat '"c:\\Program Files\\git\\usr\\bin\\scp.exe" -i "c:\\Users\\tom\\.ssh\\azure\\id_rsa" C:\\Users\\tom\\.jenkins\\workspace\\scp-to-linux\\abc.jar tom@xy.xyz.xy.xz:abc.jar'
                bat '"c:\\Program Files\\git\\usr\\bin\\ssh.exe" -i "c:\\Users\\tom\\.ssh\\azure\\id_rsa" tom@xy.xyz.xy.xz ls -ltr'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: While doing `scp`, if you do not specify the *destination* file name, it will create file on remote server with the *complete source path* name. For example, in my case, it would have created file with the name `C:\Users\tom\.jenkins\workspace\scp-to-linux\abc.jar` on remote server had i not specified this syntax: `tom@xy.xyz.xy.xz:abc.jar`

Comment: I tried: pipeline {agent any stages {stage('SCP') {steps {bat '"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\scp.exe" -i "C:\\Live" "C:\\Windows\\System32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Local\\Jenkins\\.jenkins\\workspace\\MSDeploy\\abc.txt abc.txt' bat '"c:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\ssh.exe" -i "C:\Live" abc.txt ls -ltr'}}}} but showing same error 'No such directory foud'. I am trying to copy file on window server where "C:\Live" is on remote server & "C:\Windows\\System32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Local\\Jenkins\\.jenkins\\workspace\\MSDeploy\\" is workspace path.What is wrong here?