# Jenkins SSH From Windows Server To Linux Server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

How to Establish connection From Jenkins Build Server(Windows) to Linux Machines and execute the shell scripts on the Linux machine. Please let me know how it can be achieved.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: For our Environment SSH keys should not be generated. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Check updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Using SSH passwordless login: One way to achieve that is to first install [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) on your Windows machine. This will also install several helper utilities including `scp` and `ssh`. Once you have those in place, you can then simply follow the instructions explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174773/scp-from-jenkins-pipeline-script/62177557#62177557).

Pasting snippet from above link for reference.

```
stage('SCP JAR file') {
    steps {
        bat '"c:\\Program Files\\git\\usr\\bin\\ssh.exe" -i "c:\\Users\\tom\\.ssh\\azure\\id_rsa" tom@xy.xyz.xy.xz ls -ltr'
    }
}
```

---

2) Using password authentication: Using SSH is the preferred practice however, for any reason, if that's not feasible, you can connect using *password* authentication. Follow these steps:

a) Change `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on your Linux instance. Restart `sshd` service. Set password for the user with which you want to connect. Use `passwd` command for it. All steps mentioned in below link.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-password-login/

b) You may use `PuTTY` to connect using password. Refer this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116672/running-linux-script-on-remote-linux-system-using-putty

Above link explains how you can use a file (containing commands) option and it also specifies how you can run a single command using the `PuTTY` `Remote command` box which is present in `SSH` section. In the fig. shown below, if i connect using a user `ubuntu`, it will create a directory `abc` under `/home/ubuntu` and after that PuTTY will exit immediately.

[image]

Using command file option: `putty.exe -ssh user@192.168.1.1 -pw password -m C:\local\file\containing_command`

---

3) Using `plink`: You can download the executable from [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)

In case you wish to run multiple commands, create a file containing all your commands. For example,

Content of `cmds.txt`:

```
hostname
touch file
ls -ltr
```

Command:

```
c:\test>plink -ssh centos@xx.xyz.xxy.xyz -pw centos -m cmds.txt
```

Output:

[image]

Note: In case you're noticing that the first command runs and the second doesn't, try changing the format of your command file from:

```
first_cmd ; second_cmd
```

to

```
first_cmd
second_cmd
```

Also, don't forget to press `Enter` after the last command. Your file should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestions i have executed the above command from command prompt, able to lunch the putty but it is expecting the password again.

Comment: When i execute putty.exe -ssh user@192.168.1.1 -pw password  following command i am able to login with the option -m it is not working

Comment: I have used the first one (without `-m` option) and that worked for me too. In this case, it's expected that PuTTY will prompt you for password. Will have to check for the `-m` option though why it's not working for you. What error do you get? Can you paste the complete command?

Comment: i just tried with plink option and it worked for me plink.exe -ssh user@192.168.1.1 -pw password -m C:\local\file\containing_command. But now only issue is after providing the commands in the "containing_command" my first running successfully but second command is not running is there any syntax i need to provide in the file

Comment: Try this syntax once: `plink.exe -ssh user@192.168.1.1 -pw password < C:\local\file\containing_command`

Comment: Can you paste the content of your command file? I just tested and it works for me using `-m` option

Comment: sudo -i -u user ;
sudo service servicename status

Comment: Sorry @satya. I did see your message but honestly, i couldn't try. Engaged in my office work. Will still try to test your scenario hopefully by tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working with the steps provided.