# current working directory in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to do SCP from Windows Jenkins node to Linux server. In this set up, Windows machine is a Jenkins slave and the target server where i want to copy is Linux.

Below is my Jenkins pipeline script

```
stage('SCP JAR file') {
steps {
         bat 'scp c:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\migration\\test-project\\build\\libs\\ssupservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar rxp096p@server:/home/rxp096p/testing'
      }
 }
}
```

Above script works but we need to use ${env.WORKSPACE} as the current directory might change.So i tried below

```
bat 'scp ${env.WORKSPACE}\\build\\libs\\ssupservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
  rxp096p@server:/home/rxp096p/testing'
```

But it gives me error ${env.WORKSPACE}/build/libs/ssupservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar no such file or directory.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174773/scp-from-windows-to-linux-using-jenkins-pipeline-script/62177557#62177557) answer.

Comment: I dont want to hardcode entire path.I want to fetch current working directory path from environment variables or by some other way.

Comment: Did you echo the variable `${env.WORKSPACE}` and check whether the output is as expected? Also, that link was provided to help resolve the error you're getting i.e., 'no such file or directory' provided `${env.WORKSPACE}` is working as expected.

Comment: If `${env.WORKSPACE}` isn't working, try just `${WORKSPACE}`

Comment: Just noticed that you only asked in that link as well. :) I see here too you're not using the suggested way provided in that answer. Is that the reason it's not working?

Comment: @Technext {WORKSPACE} also gives me same error.When i tried echo {env.WORKSPACE} it prints the same value i.e "{env.WORKSPACE}".This way worked for me hence i have not used that way.

Comment: Can you try replacing single quote around `bat 'scp...'` to double quote as shown here? `bat "scp..."`

Comment: @Technext It worked with double quote bat "scp ........".Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems single quote used after `bat` command is not interpolating the Jenkins environment variable (`env.WORKSPACE`).

Please change

```
bat 'scp ${env.WORKSPACE}\\build\\libs\\ssupservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar rxp096p@server:/home/rxp096p/testing'
```

to

```
bat "scp ${env.WORKSPACE}\\build\\libs\\ssupservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar rxp096p@server:/home/rxp096p/testing"
```